# Django TestCase object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: python, django

I'm learning about testing in Django. I need to first create user and login before I can test anything. I have tried the following...

```
class ProjectTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.email = 'test@test.com'
        self.password = 'test'
        self.new_user = AppUser.objects.create_superuser(email=self.email, password=self.password)

        new_user = authenticate(username=self.email,
                                    password=self.password)

        login(request, new_user)
        self.assertEqual(login, True)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.new_user.delete()
```

which gives me the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'session'

I have also tried:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.email = 'test@test.com'
    self.password = 'test'        
    self.new_user = AppUser.objects.create_superuser(email=self.email, password=self.password)
    login = self.new_user.login(username=self.email, password=self.password)
```

But it states I don't have anything called login.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? You do not reference session in your code. If it does not recognize 'login', print the contents of self.new_user to make sure you are getting what you think you are getting before attempting to call a method from that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call login on a user, you call it on an instance of the test client.

```
self.client.login(username=self.email, password=self.password)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ProjectTest(TestCase):

    def test_login_feature(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='joe', password='pass')
        self.client.login(username='joe', password='pass')
        # client now authenticated and can access 
        # restricted views.
```

So this is how you would do it. Create a user and use `self.client.login` you can read more about how to use it in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.client.Client.login)